# Whats an easy way of installing a VPN client on my webhost?

Tags: linux, vpn

I have a webhosting account in the UK (Linux)

Is it possible to install some sort of a web app that will allow me to use Windows VPN client to connect and use my server's IP address as a VPN server?

Thanks,

Comment: Not programming related...

Comment: semi-related...

Comment: Looks like ServerFault would be a better place for this question...

Comment: What is the goal? To proxy your http traffic? To access files? Do you have shell access?

Answer (score 0):

pptp for client, pptpd server. There's plenty of tutorials on installing and configuring if you google those.